# Serilog does not log to file after exception has occured

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog, .net-core-3.1

I am using serilog in my .Net core 3.1 CONSOLE project. It works perfectly fine usually but if there is any exception, it logs the exception and then it stops logging all together for all subsequent runs of that app. I need to delete the log file and it starts working again.

Not sure what I am doing wrong or missing anything. Please help.

Here is the serilog configuration.

```
"Serilog": {
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\Logs\\MyLogs.log",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000,
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
    }
  }
]  }
```

And here is how I am using it in generic host

```
 return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(( hostContext,services ) =>
            {

               ...
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("AppConfigs.json");
            })
            .UseSerilog(( context,builder ) =>
            {
                builder
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
            });
```

Comment: have you read that: https://rehansaeed.com/logging-with-serilog-exceptions/  and that:https://github.com/RehanSaeed/Serilog.Exceptions

Comment: yes. I tried adding exceptions enricher but did not help. Thanks for the pointer though. @Frenchy

Comment: File permissions issues? Is it the same userid each time? In general you dont want to go logging to a random root folder like that - I doubt it's a Serilog specific issue?

Comment: It works perfectly till I hit the exception without any changes. Like SQL server offline. So I am guessing it should not be the permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid mistake on my part. The issue was

```
"fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000,
```

which is 5 kb. The exception text was much bigger which was causing it to be more than the limit. And

```
"rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
```

was not working because I forgot to add Serilog.Sink.File package. Once I added that and changed the limit, it was all fine. Thanks for the replies.